# Yii url with server static IP address

Tags: php, url, yii

I'm developping with Yii, and I need to send mail to contacts with an  link. The proble is that the code

```
Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('participant/create', array('c' => $id_contact, 'e' => $id_event));
```

returns generates the URL :

```
http://localhost/myApplication/index.php?r=participant/create&c=1&e=12
```

And such a link is useless for the remote contact who will receive it in the mail.

How can I fix it ? How to set an IP address in my url ? Any issue ?

Comment: I am still developping, so the app is hosting locally but accessible on the local network. Although, I want to test wheither it is possible.

Comment: so, to test, you simply get the URL from the email and use it on your local machine.

Comment: Ok, I can see. I am hoping to send the link to a contact who can follow it and access information on my host. If any issue, how for do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer would be to host it on a remote public server, so that Yii will generate a (non-localhost) link that anybody can access (whether via IP address or domain name).